# How to use Observable.If without calling functions

Tags: rxjs5

Currently, functions isEven and isOdd are called for each IF. Is there a way that the functions are called only when the evaluation of the IF correspond to the logic path of the function?

Example: reference of JSBin: http://jsbin.com/wegesaweti/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
var isEven = function(x) {
  console.log('function isEven called')
  return Rx.Observable.return(x + ' is even');
};    
var isOdd = function(x) {
  console.log('function isOdd called')
  return Rx.Observable.return(x + ' is odd');
};
var source = Rx.Observable.range(1,4)
  .flatMap((x) => Rx.Observable.if(
    function() { return x % 2; },
    isOdd(x),
    isEven(x)
));    
var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ' + x);
    });
```

Current output:

```
function isOdd called
function isEven called
Next: 1 is odd
function isOdd called
function isEven called
Next: 2 is even
function isOdd called
function isEven called
Next: 3 is odd
function isOdd called
function isEven called
Next: 4 is even
```

Expected output

```
function isOdd called
Next: 1 is odd
function isEven called
Next: 2 is even
function isOdd called
Next: 3 is odd
function isEven called
Next: 4 is even
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the [RXJS docuemntation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/if.md) the `thenSource` and `elseSource` need to be `Observable` (or `Scheduler` for `elseSource`).

An alternative for your problem:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.range(1,4).flatMap((x) => 
    (x % 2) == 1 ? isOdd(x) : isEven(x)
);
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/godubemano/1/edit?html,js,output